# Deno Oak Disable Cors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api, deno

I am trying to 'connect' my small `React JS` app with my `Deno API` backend on my local environment with `fetch()`.

```
   const apiUrl = `http://localhost:8000`;
  
   try{

    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((repos) => {
        console.log(repos);
        setAppState({ loading: false, repos: repos });
      });
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
```

My app is serving on `localhost:3000` and my deno api on `localost:8000`.

However, I am having problem with CORS:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I tried some suggestions like:
add line `'"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` to reactjs project `packages.json`'.

Or to add:

```
var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
        "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*"
    },
  }

fetch(apiUrl, options)
```

Or to add:

```
fetch(apiUrl, {mode: 'no-cors'})
```

However, nothing works in my case. All the time getting the same error and some additional based on suggestions.

So ,I need to disable CORS in my reactjs and deno API app to allow local dev communication between frontend and backend.

Comment: I have same issue above and no Deno solution below working? have u fixed it at Deno?

Comment: This helped me, and this SO post was the first search result in DuckDuckGo on query 'deno oak cors'. However the OP misunderstands CORS or at least misformulated the question as CORS is 'Cross Origin Resource *Sharing*' and is something that needed to be ENabled to allow the front-end to backend communication, not DISabled as the question or subject now says. Please update.

Comment: Or perhaps don't update as many people are confused about CORS, since it is a hard concept to grasp.  To clarify: what you can DISable is the 'Same-Origin policy' which all browser normally enforce. But this can NOT be disabled on the client side with a 'no-cors' indication or something but only server side, which the accepted answer explains how to do in Deno Oak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution in my case was pretty easy.

I had to import oakCors into my Deno API app.ts

```
import { oakCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";
```

after that, just add the excluded origin after app instantiation:

```
app.use(
    oakCors({
      origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }),
);
```

NOTE: I tried to set origin to `origin: false` and that did not work in my case.

For more options on Deno CORS here is a link: https://deno.land/x/cors

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Is there a chance there's something wrong with the react app?

Comment: I think "false" won't work because your browser expect CORS, so you might need to also add "no-cors". ["*", "http://localhost:3000"] worked for me

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had to first pass oakCors configuration to the app and then the routes.

```
app.use(oakCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}));
app.use(router.routes());
```

Answer (score 5):

This works just fine:

```js
app.use(oakCors({ origin: "*" }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
 ctx.response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // * for all servers, you can use your own server address
 ctx.response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'); // Which methods you want to allow
 ctx.response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); // If your request body has json
 await next(); // If you use async await in other middlewares, you must use async await here
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

place`app.use(oakCors())` before your routes like this:

```js
app.use(oakCors())
app.use(route.routes())
```

this is allow all CORS before to manage the routes